# Merging two array List together and sorting them, removing the zeroes in the process

Tags: java

I am having trouble merging one array list to another array list. For example, lets say the first array list has the numbers (1,2,3,0,0,0), and the second array list (2,5,6) the program should output (1,2,2,3,5,6). The problem with my output is that when I print using the hold variable, it gives me the output of only the second list, it does not take into account the first list. I am confused on what I need to add to fix this.

My code:

```
        List<Integer> nums1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,0,0,0);
        int m = 3;
        
        List<Integer> nums2 = Arrays.asList(2,5,6);
        int n = 3;
        
        int hold;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           hold = nums1.get(i + m);
           hold = nums2.get(i);
           
           System.out.println(hold);
        }
```

Update: sorry in advance, for some reason when I put the code in between the quotes, it never prints it in the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the first assignment.  Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  hold = nums1.get(i + m);
  System.out.println(hold);
  
  hold = nums2.get(i);
  System.out.println(hold);
}
```

Comment: The only thing is  when it prints it prints the number 1 as 0, why is that? It like overrides the one

Comment: Because you're printing those indices.  In this loop, you're printing the the 3, 4, 5 index of nums1 and the 1, 2, 3 index of nums2